# JPA 2.0 map one class to different columns of one table

Tags: jpa

i have Entity mapped to table TABLE1 with columns COLUMN1 and COLUMN2

i have class ResViewer

```
public class ResViewer() {
  private boolean flag;
  private int property;

  ...selectors

}
```

i have entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE1")
public class Table1() {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private ResViewer res1;
    private ResViewer res2;

    ...selectors

}
```

How can i map field flag of classes res1 and res2 to columnds COLUMN1 and COLUMN2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ResViewer needs to be annotated with [`@Embeddable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html), and the fields res1 and res2 must be annotated with [`@Embedded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html), and with `@AttributeOverrides`, as demonstrated in the javadoc of `@Embedded`.